# JS PHP: How to cut a part of a video and save it as audio mp3 and ogg

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, audio, video

I have a video on server, loaded in html5 video tag. I would like to save part of the video(from a specific second to another second) as audio(sound only) in mp3 and ogg formats.

in other words, wanna extract sound from second A to second B in a video and save it on server in .mp3 and .ogg formats.

can I do that with php and/or javascript(or jquery)?
ps: the video usually in .mp4 format

Comment: You will need to load the video server-side, and use FFmpeg or similar for this.